# How to close pop up in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am testing web application of angular.
I am having an issue with a popup that I cannot close.
The code is from ng-zoro frame work.

this is the HTML:
[image]

I tried everything that is in the book to close this popup.
this is the picture
[image]

I just want to press the icon that is behind this message.
for example the id is 6.

Is there any solution to press it even if the message overlay it?

All the solutions of handling popups by selenium not work, I need a way to press the element that is behind the popup.

Comment: You said that you have tried everything in the book, but you did not include any examples of what you have tried, so you are probably going to receive a few answers suggesting you to do things that you might have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a pop-up, you can simply click on the edge of the window (pop-ups close when you click outside it's box), so, clicking anywhere else would do the job.

You can select any non clickable element and then perform mouse click on it using the following syntax.

```py
{object name}.click()
```